# Populating dropdown box from database php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have some pretty simple code that is not doing what I want it to do. I just want it to take the unique numbers of the year category in my table and enter them into a dropdown box, but with this code I only get one option which says: $row['year']

Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form name="testform" method='POST' action='mainck.php'>
<?Php
require "config.php";

echo "<br>Select year first <select name=year id ='s1' onchange=AjaxFunction();>
<option value=>Select a Year</option>";

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT year from PlayerRegSeason";

foreach ($dbo->query(&sql) as $row) {
    echo "<option value=$row['year']>$row['year']</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: try with `foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {`

Comment: is that not what i already have?

Comment: You've got &sql instead of $sql

Comment: Are you running this on a web-server, is php installed and does the document have the `.php` extension?

Comment: This was it, I was running it locally thinking as I could connect, but once I loaded it onto the ftp and ran it from the server I got the database connection error and was able to fix the problem. on to making another dropdown dependent on this one and not looking foward to that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a lot of quotes in your markup. It's better to be consistent about double vs single quotes, but the following should at least work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form name="testform" method='POST' action='mainck.php'>
<?php
require "config.php";

echo "<br>Select year first <select name='year' id='s1' onchange='AjaxFunction();'>
<option value=''>Select a Year</option>";

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT year from PlayerRegSeason";

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['year']."'>".$row['year']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now the dropdown just shows : ".$row['year']."

Comment: You updated the complete code to look like above? Sounds like you might have a rogue quote somewhere that's messing it up.

Comment: Yes, and even copy and tried one that was a straight copy and paste. I feel like I've tried every combination of quotes.

Comment: @user2884621 What is the extension of your document, `.php`? Note that the php will not get parsed if it is something like `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben said, some changes would make it more likely to work. But I would keep things that don't need PHP out of it. Be sure to use the HTML properly (it won't solve this problem, but it's a good practice, tags like HEAD and BODY).

If that's still not working, make sure to check your query directly on phpMyAdmin or your MySQL client. Another thing that I usually do when I'm stuck in situations like this is *print_r()* my return.

PS.: Check again in your *foreach($dbo->query(**&sql**) as $row){* if the **&** is the sign that you want. *(I'm not exactly sure what a **&** sign would do there, so my bad if I'm wrong.)*

I changed some stuff in your code, check it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="testform" method='POST' action='mainck.php'>
            <label for="s1">Select year first</label>
            <select name='year' id ='s1' onchange='AjaxFunction();'>
                 <option value=''>Select a Year</option>
<?php
    require "config.php";

    echo "";

    $sql="SELECT DISTINCT year from PlayerRegSeason";

    $return = $dbo->query($sql);
    print_r($return);

    foreach ($return as $row) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['year']."'>".$row['year']."</option>";
    }
?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks a lot that looks like it should definitley work, but still getting the same problem. However, I don't think that anything came up from the print_r (it would have just showed up on the page, right?), so I'm thinking there is something wrong with the sql, even though I have tried the statement in myphpadmin and it gives me the results I am looking for.

Comment: What's this $dbo object that you're using? Check if you shouldn't use something like $var = $dbo->query($sql); $return = $var->result(); Or something like this. This could be one of the problems.